# How to apply exception aspect in PostSharp with multiple return statements in method?

Tags: c#, exception, postsharp

I am using PostSharp aspects for exception handling inside of Controller in ASP.NET MVC project. Simplified code is like this:

```
 [ExceptionAspect(AspectPriority = 1)]
 public ActionResult MarkeSettings()
 {
   try{
       SaveData();
       NotifyUser("success");
       return RedirectToAction("A");
     }
   catch(Exception ex){
      NotifyUser(ex.Message);
      return RedirectToAction("B");
   }
 }
```

I have class `ExceptionAspect` that inherits from `OnExceptionAspect` class. In `OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)` method I set `args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;`.

So, how can I get rid of this `try/catch` block and control the program execution flow and take an appropriate action for `ReturnRedirectToAction()`? I read about [Sharing state between advices](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator) , but couldn't figure out how to apply it on my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `ExceptionAspect` to your controller's method, it wraps the method with the `try/catch` block and calls `OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)` from the introduced catch block.

This means that you can move your common exception handling code from the catch block to the `OnException` method inside the aspect. I suppose that you want to redirect user to a specific action when exception happens. `RedirectToAction` is a protected method of the controller that returns `RedirectToRouteResult`. So you would need to construct and return a correct `RedirectToRouteResult` instance in the `OnException` method. To change the return value of the method set the `args.ReturnValue` to the desired value, and `args.FlowBehavior` to `FlowBehavior.Return`.

Below is the example of the `OnExceptionAspect` implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class RedirectOnExceptionAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public string ToAction { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // NotifyUser(args.Exception.Message);

        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;

        object controller = ((ControllerBase) args.Instance).ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        args.ReturnValue = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"action", this.ToAction},
                    {"controller", controller}
                });
    }
}
```

Applying to controller method:

```
[RedirectOnException(ToAction = "B")]
public ActionResult MarkeSettings()
{
    SaveData();
    NotifyUser("success");
    return RedirectToAction("A");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Async action methods. args.FlowBehavior is ignored on them.

Comment: PostSharp supports flow behavior in async methods starting from version 5.0.